# PHP - Check if server is offline and not show a warning in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, fsockopen

i'm currently checking if a server(in this case 192.168.1.135) is online with this php code:

```
<?php 
$fp = fsockopen("192.168.1.135", 443, $errno, $errstr, 0.4); //(line 47)
if (!$fp) {
  echo "OFFLINE";
}
else{
 echo "ONLINE";
}
?>
```

I have this code on my own server 192.168.1.130 using XAMPP (on LAN ofcourse)

So, if this server is offline the output will be:

```
Warning: fsockopen(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 47
OFFLINE
```

it should just be "OFFLINE". How to show just OFFLINE without the warning?

I think XAMPP will send me the warning when the server is down. but how should I do to not show the warning? I don't find a setting for this in XAMPP, anyone know?

if no, how should i do the line 47 correct even when the server is down(offline)?

When the server is online, this will work perfecly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [silence operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@` to suppress the warning:

```
$fp = @fsockopen("192.168.1.135", 443, $errno, $errstr, 0.4); //(line 47)
```

---

Side note: As you see, the `@` operator suppressed the warning as you requested. But be careful. A message like for example 'No route to host' will being also suppressed. (Mostly if **your** network connection isn't available) So you cannot be sure, that the server is offline. You should additionally output `$errmsg` if `fsockopen()` fails to see the reason.

Comment: Note that you should *only do it in very specific cases*, since `fsockopen()` throws a warning when connection fails, and that's exactly what you're testing for, it's OK to use the silence operator.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'm with you. `@` should be used with care, but in this case it is OK

Comment: Yes, I was adding it for future reference (I would be a happy ninja if you'd added it to your answer as a sidenote).

Comment: I hope you are a *happy ninja* now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this script

```
$fp = fsockopen("192.168.1.135", 443, $errno, $errstr, 0.4);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: 192.168.1.135\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: 443 is the default port for HTTPS, so it probably **is** a webserver.